# WYGWAM PHP errors in CP after upgrade

Tags: php, error, wygwam

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: config
Filename: wygwam/helper.php
Line Number: 535
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: config
Filename: wygwam/ft.wygwam.php
Line Number: 430
```

How can I resolve this?

I upgraded EE to 2.5.5 and Wygwam to 2.6.3. It is an MSM site.

The problem persists after visiting the settings page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should fix you up:

https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/undefined_index_config_after_upgrade#reply_10005608

You'll need to re-save the Matrix field that contains your Wygwam field.

-Lisa

Comment: I can’t stress enough how important it is generally to visit that settings page. It bites me in Wygwam, and it *really* bites my butt in Matrix.

Comment: They’re just being playful.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Where, exactly, are you seeing this error in the CP?  Thank you!  It would be great to know the exact steps to reproduce this.

Comment: On the "Edit Entry" screen when a Wygwam field is present.

Comment: After you visited the Settings page, did you go re-save the particular entry?  This was reported before: https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/undefined_index_config_after_upgrade - and that was the solution.  I know you visited Settings, just seeing if re-saving that entry removes the error.  Thank you!

Comment: Bingo: Wygwam field inside a matrix. Resaved field, all is good.

Comment: If you make that the official answer I can accept it so you'll get Stack Exchange gold stars.

Comment: nooo, the final answer was like in the post you linked to: resave the Matrix field with a Wygwam field inside it.

Comment: I've had one of those days, you know? ;) Thanks!

Comment: I had to resave all WYGWAM fields, and I think, Matrix and Playa fields just to be safe.