# ACK! Can't edit fields - getting WYGWAM error after EE & WYGWAM upgrade

Tags: wygwam

EE v2.7.3 - Build Date: 20131210   /    Wygwam - 3.2.2

when I go to:

CP Home -> Add-ons -> Fieldtypes

*OR*

CP Home -> Administration -> Channel Fields -> (any field group even if there is no wygwam field in the group)

ERROR I get:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Use of undefined
>   constant FT_PATH - assumed 'FT_PATH' Filename:
>   wygwam/ft.wygwam.ee1.php Line Number: 7 A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Warning
>   Message: require_once(FT_PATHwygwam/config.php)
>   [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required 'FT_PATHwygwam/config.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in 
>   third_party/wygwam/ft.wygwam.ee1.php on line 7

I can get to CP Home -> Modules -> Wygwam -> Editor Configurations - and I resaved all my wygwam fields as per this post: [WYGWAM PHP errors in CP after upgrade](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/3707/wygwam-php-errors-in-cp-after-upgrade)

THAT post mentions a post to look at on https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic but that info is "retired"  :-/

> Sorry, the community that you’re looking for has been retired and is
>   no longer available. If you need help, please contact the company
>   you're looking for directly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you uploaded the EE1 version of Wygwam.  Not sure how that’s possible since Wygwam hasn’t shipped with EE1 files in a long time. Try re-downloading Wygwam from http://devot-ee.com and uploading the system/expressionengine/third_party/wgywam/ and themes/third_party/wygwam/ folders again.